# How to normalize the distribution in the tuples?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tuples, normalization

I tried to do some normalization in my code and I have a list with inner-list:

```
a  = [[ ('1', 0.03),
        ('2', 0.03),
        ('3', 0.06)]
      [ ('4', 0.03),
        ('5', 0.06),
        ('6', 0.06)]
      [ ('7', 0.07),
        ('8', 0.014),
        ('9', 0.07)]
                    ]
```

I tried to normalized the distribution in the tuples to get list `b`

```
b  = [[ ('1', 0.25),
        ('2', 0.25),
        ('3', 0.50)]
      [ ('4', 0.20),
        ('5', 0.40),
        ('6', 0.40)]
      [ ('7', 0.25),
        ('8', 0.50),
        ('9', 0.25)]
                    ]
```

And I tried:

```
for i in a:
    for n, (ee,ww) in enumerate(i):
      i[n] = (ee,ww/sum(ww))
```

But it failed.

How to get `b` in python?

Answer (score 0):

```
a  = [[ ('1', 0.03),
        ('2', 0.03),
        ('3', 0.06)],
      [ ('4', 0.03),
        ('5', 0.06),
        ('6', 0.06)],
      [ ('7', 0.07),
        ('8', 0.14),
        ('9', 0.07)]
                    ]

for i in a:
    s = sum(v[1] for v in i)
    i[:] = [(v[0], v[1] / s) for v in i]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(a)
```

Prints:

```
[[('1', 0.25), ('2', 0.25), ('3', 0.5)],
 [('4', 0.2), ('5', 0.4), ('6', 0.4)],
 [('7', 0.25), ('8', 0.5), ('9', 0.25)]]
```

Note:

`i[:] = [(v[0], v[1] / s) for v in i]` replaces all values in list `i` with new values from the list comprehension.